# When I try to import scrapy in VSCode I get an import error message

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, scrapy, anaconda, modulenotfounderror

I installed VSCode and all the python extensions, I have anaconda installed and set:
`C:\Users\username\anaconda3\python.exe` as the path to my python interpreter in VSCode, but when I run:

```py
import scrapy
```

it gives me this error message:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing etree: The specified module could not be found.
```

or

```
No module named scrapy
```

Answer (score 1):

After spending hours with the same issue the solution that worked was:

Go to the anaconda prompt and type :

1. pip uninstall lxml
2. pip install lxml

That should solve the issue.

If the issue isn't resolved then add anaconda to environment variables, you can learn that from here:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Wt00qGlh3s